# Selenium Select - Using select took long time so select by index is failed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to run a script using python and using select to choose the first item in drop down list:

```
my_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("some_id"))
sleep(0.25)
my_select.select_by_index(1)
```

Because the select took some time, I have to do sleep before select by index.
I want to change the sleep to another option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case selecting takes some time you should put some delay after `my_select.select_by_index(1)`, not before it.
You should use Expected Condition explicit wait here instead of dummy hardcoded pause of `sleep(0.25)`
Let's say after applying the `my_select.select_by_index(1)` some element with text `Option 1` will appear. In this case you can use command like this:

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Option 1']")))
```

In order to use such `wait`  object you will need these imports and object initialization:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. At first, I did that:

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="some_id"]/option[2]'))).click()
But it took longer than doing the select with the const sleep. Do you know why?

I also don't know which text will apear, I just want to select the first one.

Comment: Can you share a link to the page you are working on and all your relevant code?

Comment: Unfortunately It's locked by username and password, but I'll explain myself: I'm trying to make an appointment earlier and I need to click on date and time. After I click on the date I need to choose the time, because I don't care about the time, I don't know the time and it's very hard to succeed to make it, I want it to run as fast as I can.
Earlier I used the wait until as I wrote, but because it was slow, everytime I tried I almost succeed to click on the time, but someone did it before me.

Comment: I see, but it is still not clear enough. Expected conditions should not make your code slower, if you use it correctly it makes your code much faster. To see what's wrong here I have to see your code and the page you are working on. I understand you can't share it. If so you will have to ask some your colleague for help